# tinyint in SQL Server to byte in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In database management and application development we must be mindful of space and memory requirements. I have always been taught to use the data type that uses the least amount of space for your needs.

In my scenario, I have a column in a table that stores values {0,1,2,3,4} (SQL Server 2012). For this I chose to use the tinyint datatype. These values are pulled from the database into a C# application. Currently, I cannot get this tinyint data type to convert to a byte. When I try, I get an error "Cannot implicitly convert int to byte". If I change the datatype in the application to an integer, I can pull it just fine. Same with a string.

For performance purposes, is it okay to use integers throughout my entire application where I would normally use byte? If not, how do you convert an integer to a byte?

This is the code that I use that gives an error:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT securityLevel FROM security WHERE employeeID=@empID;";

using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(connParam))
{
  dbConn.Open();

  byte level = 0;

  using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, dbConn))
  {

    dbCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", "12345");

    using (SqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (dbReader.Read())
      {
        level = dbReader.GetByte(0);
      }
    }

  }

  Console.WriteLine(level);
  Console.ReadLine();

}
```

I have also tried:

```
level = (byte)dbReader.GetValue(0);
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `GetVaue(0)` and query the return value in the Immediate Windows in VS, it will tell you what the type is. (i.e. `dbReader.GetValue(0).GetType()`)

Comment: Are you sure `securityLevel` is a `tinyInt`? from the error you are getting it sounds like it is a `int`. How are you checking that it is a `tinyInt`, also can you show your connection string? If you are using `AttachDBFilename` the database you are making schema changes to is likely not the database you are using in your program.

Comment: look up INFORMATION_SCHEMA and verify the column type

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you were correct to pick `TINYINT` as the datatype if you are storing only 0 - 4.

Yes, `TINYINT` equates to a `byte` in .Net. You can see a list of mappings here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx

No, you did not actually use `TINYINT` when creating the table, else you would not be getting this error. The error message is very specific about the source datatype being `INT`.

No, do not use `INT` to store these values. That is unnecessary and what you are attempting to do (i.e. `TINYINT` and `byte`) is perfectly valid and I have done it many times.

Assuming you do not have millions of rows of data in that table and constant hits against it, run the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [security] ALTER COLUMN [securityLevel] TINYINT NOT NULL;
```

(I am assuming that the column is currently `NOT NULL` and in that case, if you leave off the `NOT NULL` in the `ALTER TABLE` statement, it will change the field to `TINYINT NULL`. If the field isn't currently `NOT NULL`, then just leave that part off)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. Since I am using only the 0 - 4 values, would a char(1) not use less space? If so, why would I not use this?

Comment: @nehi_d : a `CHAR(1)` = 1 byte, and `TINYINT` = 1 byte. There is no difference in physical space taken. But most likely the TINYINT would perform better in JOINs and WHERE clauses. It is possible that CHAR(1) _might_ do as well IF you used a binary collation (such as `SQL_General_BIN` or `Latin1_General_BIN`) when you create the column (or alter it with that definition), but it seems like it really is a number, so best to keep it that way. It also makes it better for doing `ORDER BY [SecurityLevel]` or `WHERE [SecurityLevel] > 3` (or something like that).

Comment: @nehi_d : were you able to test this out? Did it work?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote the following LinqPad (against SqlServer express) to verify that you can read in a tinyint as a byte using .NET and SqlServer:

```
var cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = @".\Sqlexpress", InitialCatalog = "Medallion_OData_Tests_CustomersContext251990930203", IntegratedSecurity = true };
using (var c = new SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();   

    var cmd = c.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CAST(1 AS tinyint)";
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    reader.GetByte(0).Dump();
}
```

This suggests to me that the actual securityLevel column in your database is not of the type TINYINT. To verify, why not temporarily modify your select query to include a CAST to TINYINT as in my example? If this works, that will confirm that the table schema is the problem.

Other ways to check the actual table schema include querying sys.columns or highlighting the name of the table in SqlServer Management Studio and hitting ALT+F1.

Answer (score 2):

I think safest way is to use [Convert.ToByte Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7x4400t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
level = Convert.ToByte(dbReader.GetValue(0));
```

It converts from many value types to byte.